How to emit socket message in server side Next API request
I have a POST request handler where I receive a POST request from an external website ( Bank sends POST request on my Next API route) after a successful payment. My goal is to emit a new event and message when the POST request indicating payment success is received from the bank. However, I couldn't find any solutions.
This is my custom server code

const { createServer } = require("http");
const next = require("next");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "localhost";
const port = 3000;
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const httpServer = createServer(handler);

  const io = new Server(httpServer);

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("donation", (donation) => {
      io.emit("donation", donation);
    });
    socket.on("payout", (payout) => {
      io.emit("payout", payout);
    });
  });

  httpServer
    .once("error", (err) => {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
    });
});

This is my API request handler:
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io(process.env.HOST as string);

export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
  socket.emit("donation", data);
  return new Response("Order completed", { status: 200 });
}

